# Using DB built-in functions in linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is it possible to use the CE Database's built-in functions such as those math functions POWER, SIN, COS in WP7's LINQ to SQL?  I couldn't find any samples on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement will be fully translated to SQL:

```
TblUsers.OrderBy (tu => Math.Pow(tu.PkUserID, 5))
```

Output

```
DECLARE @p0 Float = 5

SELECT ...
FROM [tblUser] AS [t0]
ORDER BY POWER(CONVERT(Float,[t0].[pkUserID]), @p0)
```

The following methods are not supported by Linq2SQL:

- `Math.DivRem(Int32, Int32, Int32)`
- `Math.DivRem(Int64, Int64, Int64)`
- `Math.IEEERemainder(Double, Double)`

`Math.Round()` always rounds away from zero in Linq2Sql. In .Net it uses [Banker's rounding](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_BankersRounding.htm).

Comment: Wow, using the C# Math functions in the Linq statement directly actually works.  How does it know to convert the C# Math functions to the CE's built in functions?  But thanks!

Comment: For some insight into (and a case study on) how providers work, you might read [Matt Warren's series on building an IQueryable provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx).